# Ext2-ext3 drives permission

Tags: permissions

I need to format a drive with Ext2 or Ext3 file system and copy a film DCP on it. I've used GParted to format the drive but cannot copy the DCP into the drive as it says I do not have the permission. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with a live DVD to boot. Disks gives me the option to format only on Ext4 which is no good for me. I did try to format with Ext4 and I can copy just fine but the drive has to be Ext2 or 3. I'm very new to Ubuntu, please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ext4 is new but also holds compatibility with other programs that are old and restrict themselves to ext2/3 a lot of times (depending on the application).  Either way, formatting with any of these three should not give this error.

You need to go into console and mount it to a folder your user has full access to like this (and we're going to assume your partition is `/dev/sdc1` and this is going to start from the beginning - aka GParted never happened here)

```
user@host:~$ mkdir mntDCP
user@host:~$ sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdc1
user@host:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 mntDCP/
user@host:~$ sudo chown user:user -R mntDCP/
```

If this doesn't work let me know so we can try other options.

Also if you could explain why Ext4 is such **blasphemy** it may help find the solution quicker as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! I' will try it now. The film festival I'm sending the DCP to specified Ext2 or 3 as some of their servers are pretty old. I just don't understand why it locks the newly formatted drive and can't do a simple action as Copy/paste.